# How can I delete an element of an ArrayList from another ArrayList in java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists `array1` and `array2`.

In both ArrayLists there can be different numbers, but in `array2` it's always just one number.
In an `onClickListener` I need the number of `array2` to be deleted from `array1`.

For example:

```
ArrayList array1 = new Arraylist(2,1,4,6,3);
ArrayList array2 = new Arraylist(1);
```

Then I tried:

```
array1.remove(array2)
```

but nothing happens...

What is the best way to achieve that?

For Context:

I have three fragments, one where you can see your deck `DeckKartenFragment` and two where you can choose your card `RadlerKarte` and `HopfentrunkKarte`. I have two ImageViews, where you can put the chosen cards.

I want that each card can only be chosen once. For that I made two Arrays. One in which all chosen cards are `deck.deck` (Is stored in class `deck`) and one in which the current chosen card of the ImageView is `deck1WelcheKarte`.

```
//Check if card is already chosen// 
if (deck.deck.contains(1) == true){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "example" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        deck.cardchosen.clear();
                    }
if (deck.deck.contains(1) == false){
                        deck.deck.add(1);  //Add Card to deck//
                        deck.deck.removeAll(deck1WelcheKarte);  //Remove card that was chosen before from deck//
                        deck1WelcheKarte.clear(); //Reset card that is chosen to current card//
                        deck1WelcheKarte.add(1);}}
```

Now if I chose my first card everything works fine, when I replace that card with a new one it still works. But when i replace that card again with my first card, the number for that first card seems to be still in `deck`, because my app goes to makeToast instead of add new card to deck...

Comment: `removeAll` may be instead?

Comment: but isn't then every number of array1 deleted?

Comment: tried but still nothing happens

Comment: these are `ArrayList`s, _NOT_ arrays, I guess. How about you provide a minimal example?

Comment: edited example in

Comment: @gipi Did you mean `array1.remove(array2.get(0));` or something similar?

Comment: I don't know, that's my question what to use there. But I just tried with .get(0) but then app crashes...

Comment: [of course you're wrong or you do not provide the entire context](https://onecompiler.com/java/3wnjfwjvz)

Comment: mhm, then the reason must be somewhere else, but context is a little bit much...

Comment: edited context if it helps @Eugene

Comment: that is by far not what I meant. you need to provide a _minimal_, _reproducible_ example, which, so far, you have not.

Comment: ok now I edited again and I hope it is not to much

Answer (score 4):

```
for(int i : array2) {
    array1.remove(i)
}
```

this way you dont have to chack if array2 contains any element, it also covers multiple elements

Comment: still doesn't work, but I also had to change int to object out of some reason...

Answer (score 2):

okey then try this code and copare it to yours:

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(6);
        // ArrayList is kind of lacking right constructor so we have to insert values manually
        for(int i : new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}) {
            a.add(i);
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>(1);
        b.add(1);

        // integer is important if we use int, it will remove by index
        for(Integer i : b) {
            a.remove(i);
        }

        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Comment: thanks but as it still doesn't work I assume the error is somewhere else...

Comment: yes it is you have to be strong and find it

Answer (score 1):

Following the previous answer, which is a good one, you have to change the type of your java.uti.ArrayList because Java Collections don't support primitive types.
Actually, when you try to add a primitive type element into the ArrayList, the value gets implicitly wrapped by an Object class of its own type, for example
This statement `array1.add(1);` -> It's same as -> `array1.add(new Integer(1));`

Here is an example to let you understand:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int myArray[] = { 2, 1, 4, 6, 3 };

        List<Integer> arrayList1 = new ArrayList();
        for (int elem : myArray) {
            arrayList1.add(elem);
        }

        List<Integer> arrayList2 = new ArrayList();
        arrayList2.add(2);

        System.out.println("array of int: " + Arrays.toString(myArray));
        System.out.println("arrayList2 (List of " + arrayList2.get(0).getClass().getName() + " ): " + arrayList2);

        System.out.println("Before remove - arrayList1: " + arrayList1);

        for (Object a : arrayList2) {
            System.out.println("Removing element (type " + a.getClass().getName() + "): " + a);
            arrayList1.remove(a);
        }

        System.out.println("After remove - arrayList1" + arrayList1);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
array of int: [2, 1, 4, 6, 3]
arrayList2 (List of java.lang.Integer ): [2]
Before remove - arrayList1: [2, 1, 4, 6, 3]
Removing element (type java.lang.Integer): 2
After remove - arrayList1[1, 4, 6, 3]
```

As you see from the code, I just printed out the name of the class which is used when you add any `int` to the `java.util.List` of Object, and they actually get wrapped by java.lang.Integer class.